# Putting controls into a gridview Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a list of objects, Each object has 3 properties..i want to iterate through the list and put them inside a gridview.

```
public void PutAllObjects in a GridView(List<CommentsObject>commentsData)
{
    int num=0;
     foreach(var item in commentsData)
     {
              Image img=new Image();
              img.imageUrl=item.ImageOfUser;
              Hyperlink hl=new Hyperlink();
              hl.Text="<br/>"+item.UsersName;
              GridView1.Rows[num++].Cells[0].Controls.Add(img);
              GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Controls.Add(hl);
              lbl=new Label();
              lbl.Text=item.UsersComment
              GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Controls.Add(lbl);

     }

}
```

What I should get is my GridView1 having 40 rows. Each row has got 2 columns..the first column has got an image with a hyperlink, and the second column has got the users comments(label)..

Am i right in hte way i write code? or is there a better way to achieve what i want

Comment: what happens if the gridview and the list are not of the same size?

Comment: Why should be the same size..? i allowed paging..shouldnt the rest of the rows spill to the next pages?

Comment: if there are **40 rows** in the GridView and the list contains **41 items** the foreach loop will break on `GridView1.Rows[41]`

Comment: Why are you doing this in the CodeBehind Dynamically? Can you edit the ASPX?

Comment: How do i pass to the next page in the gridview?

Comment: Casper,,if i only knew how to put 2 controls in one cell, then feed it with the information from the commentsData List

Comment: @CasparKleijne let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1106/discussion-between-withflyingcolors-and-caspar-kleijne)

Comment: would you be so kind to ask the question with all relevant information? It is very hard to give a proper answer if you keep behind requirements ;)

Comment: Casper all the information is given. I have a list of 40 objects..each object has got 3 properties..I want put two controls in one cell and another one in another cell. Both cells i want to save in a row...and iterate all the rows..while adding them to the Gridview.. The problem is I dont want the foreach loop to break..so how do i categorize the whole thing to pages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather do something like this.

```
GridView1.DataSource = commentsData;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you want to only bind two columns you could do the following.

```
var source = from p in commentsData
             select new {p.ImageOfUser, "<br/>" + p.UsersName, p.UsersComment };
GridView1.DataSource = source;
GridView1.DataBind();

  <asp:GridView ID="gvView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgName" imageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageOfUser") %>'></asp:Image>
                            <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyperLink" Text='<%# Bind("UsersComment") %>' ></asp:Hyperlink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Text='<%# Bind("UsersComment") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see above the Image and Hyperlink are both within ItemTempate, which means they will be shown within one cell within the gridview.

Comment: Yeah, but if i do that..how will the grid view know what property to put into what control..how does it know to put the comment property in the second cell for example..no sorry Jethro,,your solution wont work

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, ok when you create your GridView you can Specify the Columns, Ie first column has Image, Second Column has Hyperlink, Third Column has Label. Then just bind certain properties when the datasource gets bind. eg, you set the imageUrl when the datasource is bound.

Comment: Again,,how will the gridview know what controls to put in what cells.. i use 2 cells per Gridview row

Comment: Jethro..how the hell do you do it? bound different properties and put them inside controls that are located in to cells

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, I'll complete the example above. Give me a minute.

Comment: Will it work that way,,i need to put 2 template fields to represent the 2 sets..and bind the data the way you told me to to make it to work

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, please check the completed Example above.

Comment: I will check it when i get home tonight (in about 4 hours)

Comment: @Jethro let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1107/discussion-between-withflyingcolors-and-jethro)